# Joining dataframe in for loop

Tags: python

My code won't work... it gives me `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified`

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle 

list = ["ZILLOW2.csv", "ZILLOW3.csv", "ZILLOW4.csv", 
"ZILLOW6.csv", "ZILLOW7.csv", "ZILLOW8.csv"]
maindf = pd.DataFrame()       
for x in list:  
    df = pd.read_csv(x)    
    if x == "ZILLOW2.csv":
        maindf = pd.DataFrame(df)
    else:
        maindf = maindf.join(df)

print(maindf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle 

list = ["ZILLOW2.csv", "ZILLOW3.csv", "ZILLOW4.csv", 
"ZILLOW6.csv", "ZILLOW7.csv", "ZILLOW8.csv"]
maindf = pd.DataFrame()       
for x in list:  
    df = pd.read_csv(x)    
    if x == "ZILLOW2.csv":
        maindf = pd.DataFrame(df)
    else:
```

> ```
>         maindf = pd.concat([maindf, df], axis=1)
> ```

```
print(maindf)
```